# vscode debugger - cannot stop or see processes in call satck - flask

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code

I am used to debug multiprocessing apps with vscode debugger. When I initiated processes I could always see them in the call stack like this:

[image]

I could place breakpoints in the code and the processces stopped when they hit them.

For some reason that feature stopped working for me (maybe because of the latest update?).
Now all I can see if the call stack like this:

[image]

I can stop the main thread with breakpoints but now I cannot step into a running process.

Here is my launch.json file

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "Source/app.py",
                "FLASK_ENV": "development",
                "FLASK_DEBUG": "0"
            },
            // "justMyCode": false,
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload"
            ],
            "jinja": true
        }
    ]
}
```

The way I initiate the processes did not change (multiprocessing python lib) and also the code didn't change, I went back several commits (to when I know I did manage to step into a process) and it also didn't work.

I can see that the processes are doing their job properly but cannot make them stop at any break point.

I had read that the [latest update](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_46) did add something about the configuration of the debugger but it does not seem related.

Comment: Which launch config are you using?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "step into a running process"?

Comment: I cannot say what happened but without me changing anything (as far as I can say) the problem stopped appearing. I can now see the proccesses in the call stack and step into them as in place a breakpoint and any process that is running will pause there.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `--no-reload` to Flask - this disables auto-reloading, which is what necessitates the use of two processes in the first place. So it's just debugging one process.

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR

it's the [expected](https://That%20is%20expected.%20When%20there%20is%20only%20one%20session%20we%20do%20not%20show%20it%20in%20the%20call%20stack%20view%20(to%20simplify).%20Thus%20in%20that%20case%20it%20is%20not%20collapsable.) behavior somehow! I'll cite the source:

> That is expected. When there is only one session we do not show it in the call stack view (to simplify). Thus in that case it is not collapsable.

---

### The long part:

I'm experiencing the same behavior now.

Here's how it used to be and should be:
[image: how it should look like]

And here's how it is shown:
[image: how it actually looks like]

VSCode does that for all configuration types: debugpy, node.

The interesting part is when I launch any other (or even the same configuration as another instance/process), both processes immediately appear and don't disappear back until I stop all of them. If I start again with 0 processes running, I get the same behavior consistently. If I have 1 shown process and select "restart" from its popup menu, it will restart and no processes will be shown again. I tried reloading VSCode, but that didn't change a thing.

For example, here's my launch.json config I'm running:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "dcss webtiles server:run:local",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "debugpy",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/docker-crawl/src/crawl-ref/source",
      "program": "./webserver/server.py",
      "console": "internalConsole",
    },
  ]
}
```